# Weblogic - How to refer to a shared JAR library from a WAR

Tags: maven, jar, shared-libraries, war, weblogic12c

In Weblogic, I have a WAR application that needs to reference a shared library deployed as a JAR.

Is that possible?

I have tried these approaches unsuccessfully

**Approach 1**: Refer to the JAR in weblogic.xml:

```
<library-ref>
    <library-name>my-shared-jar</library-name>
</library-ref>
```

Result: classes from the JAR are not found during deployment (`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`)

**Approach 2**: Refer to the JAR in weblogic-application.xml: same code, same unsuccessful result because apparently weblogic-application.xml can only be used with EARs

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Shared libraries do not make sense in an application server...

Comment: Well, this library contains dependencies to a common framework as well as a common caching configuration so not every war using it has a copy of the whole framework and tries to use the same cache (which is giving ClassLoader errors)

Comment: you normally configure share libraries within a EAR, where a common library (jar) may be used by an ejb module, a WAR and so on, all packaged within the same EAR

Comment: If my requirements are to have 6 different WARs access a common shared library (in JAR format), would it be possible?

Comment: than you can make it part of the ear file.

Comment: What EAR file @khmarbaise? I only have 6 WARs and one shared library in a JAR format (or now in a WAR format, as exposed in the answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is the following workaround:

1. Create a new module packaged as a WAR and adding as the sole dependency the previous JAR module
2. Deploy as shared library the new WAR
3. The rest of the poms reference the JAR module with scope `provided`
4. Every service in a WAR references the new (WAR) module in it's weblogic.xml

Comment: correct, you must reference a war file as shared library:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13706/libraries.htm#WLPRG351